# Symfony/Doctrine users in multiple databases

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, subdomain, fosuserbundle

For a project we would like to use multiple databases containing different kinds of users. The website is divided over multiple subdomains. That means: 1 subdomain has 1 database. We have 1 central database to keep up with the existing subdomain databases.

In the central database, we have administrator users that must be able to administrate every subdomain application. In the other databases we have subdomain specific users. Users are stored as Doctrine entities (FOS User bundle for Symfony 2) and are tied to other entities (foreign key constraints) by their id's. The entities are the same for the central database and subdomain databases.

The users must be bound to subdomain specific entries (read: instances of entities). For subdomain specific users this will be no problem, but we have no clue how to achieve this for administrator users (which are in the central database). The foreign key constraints can not be met, since the administrator users do not "exist" in the subdomain specific database.

Refactoring some of the entities would be no problem. We hope you guys have any advise for us. Thanks in advance.

P.S.
We are able to switch between all databases easily. This is possible throughout the whole application, except for the login. This is handled by the FOS User bundle

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use one base user entity for all users in the subdomain, in a centralized place, and for each subdomain, there will be an extended user entity, with extra information stored, related to the specific subdomain. Possible structure for that can use single table inheritance, but it is not a must.